# ASM: Check if no key is pressed

Tags: assembly

I got a mission from school to build a snake game in assembly.
I have done all the game, but I can't figure a way to do one thing - make the snake countinue moving in the same dirction while no key is pressed.

Currently, after each step, my code call this code to get the next key:
`mov ah,1h
int 21h ; store at al`
But this code wait until the user will press something, so he is not good for that case.
Is someone know a code that after some time, if no key is pressed, countinue the code?
Thanks in addition :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  mov  ah, 0Bh  ;CHECK IF ANY KEY WAS PRESSED.
  int  21h      ;RESULT IN AL : ==0:NO KEY, !=0:KEY.
  cmp  al, 0
  je   JUMP_TO_MOVE_SNAKE
;GET PRESSED KEY.
  mov ah,1h
  int 21h
JUMP_TO_MOVE_SNAKE:
  ...
```

Service `0Bh` doesn't stop the execution of the code, so you can know when a key is pressed or when it is not.

Comment: The nice thing about `INT 21/AH=0Bh` vs `INT 16/AH=01` is that the former check the STDIN, not the physical keyboard, since DOS2+. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Have the interrupt set a variable. Use a timer to clear it right after it is read. Use the variable to determine which code to execute: straight/left/right

Comment: Hi, but I did not get your answer. My problem was that the program had waited until a key will be pressed and if no key is pressed - the program will not continue. I already have the function you mentioned so if you may be more clear about your answer?